# Bring text infront of line div

Tags: html, css

Hello I have some text and a line that I need to go through the text without overlapping it.

Here is the goal:

[image]

Here is what I have so far:

[image]

Some reason I cannot get the text to overpower and put the line behind it. Ive tried my best to figure it out on my own but I have failed so I decided to turn to stack overflow.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="section-3-left">
  <div class="section-3-left-line"></div>
  <div class="section-3-left-text">
    <p>CASE RESULTS</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.section-3-left {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
}

.section-3-left-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 383px;
    text-align: center;
}

.section-3-left-line {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 250px;
    height: 1px;
    width: 102.8%;
    background-color: #c61000;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle link:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yfh87zzr/)

Any help would be greatly apprechiated. Thanks!

Comment: Add z-index:-1 to the class .section-3-left-line

Answer (score 2):

```html
    <style>
        .section-3-left {
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
            position: absolute;
        }

        .section-3-left-text {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 383px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .section-3-left-line {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 250px;
            height: 1px;
            padding-right: 40%;
            background-color: #c61000;
        }

        .section-3-right-line {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 250px;
            height: 1px;
            padding-left: 40%;
            background-color: #c61000;
        }
    </style>

<body>
<div class="section-3-left">
    <div class="section-3-left-line"></div>
    <div class="section-3-right-line"></div>

    <div class="section-3-left-text">
        <p>CASE RESULTS</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: i might have to go this route, 2 seperate lines. I was just wondering if there was a way to do it with one line

Answer (score 1):

Play with the `z-index`. I added extra `background-color` to the text to simulate the image. If you set the `z-index` of the line to `1` you will see the red line on top of the text. I hope this helps.

```css
.section-3-left {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
}

.section-3-left-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 383px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:green;
}

.section-3-left-line {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 250px;
    height: 1px;
    width: 102.8%;
    background-color: #c61000;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-3-left">
  <div class="section-3-left-line"></div>
  <div class="section-3-left-text">
    <p>CASE RESULTS</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to make the background transparent instead of green

Comment: just put your image there and remove the background color

Comment: which image should i put

Comment: i was thinking in your question there is an image you are using, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This is the css and html use two dive t create line and use @media to make it responsive

```
.section-3-left {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
}

.section-3-left-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;

    text-align: center;
}

.section-3-left-line {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 250px;
    height: 1px;
    width: calc(100% - 55%);
    background-color: #c61000;
}
.section-3-right-line {
    background-color: #c61000;
    float: right;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    top: 250px;
    width: calc(100% - 55%);
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .section-3-right-line{
        width: calc(100% - 70%)!important;
    }
    .section-3-left-line {
        width: calc(100% - 70%)!important;
    }
}
<div class="section-3-left">
<div class="section-3-left-line"></div>
<div class="section-3-right-line"></div>
<div class="section-3-left-text">
    <p>CASE RESULTS</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that using below codes, see we don't want a different tag to assign red line `before and after` of `.section-3-left-text`, so `.section-3-left-line` not needed. Instead style that using pseudo selectors `:before and :after` in  `.section-3-left-text` and align them using `vw` as `percentage` won't work for that. This way your `image` will be at `bottom` then `text` above along-with `right and left-side border`, try as below

```css
.section-3-left{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.section-3-left > img{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   z-index:1;
}
.section-3-left > .section-3-left-text{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:9;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  background:transparent;
 }
.section-3-left > .section-3-left-text:before{
 content:'';
 width:50vw;
 height:1px;
 background:red;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:2;
 top:50%;
 left:-50vw;
 transform:translate(0,-50%);
}
.section-3-left > .section-3-left-text:after{
 content:'';
 width:50vw;
 height:1px;
 background:red;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:2;
 top:50%;
 right:-50vw;
 transform:translate(0,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="section-3-left">
  <div class="section-3-left-text">
    <p>CASE RESULTS</p>
  </div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1250x500">
</div>
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4smz0o76/1/).

Answer (score 1):

I once had almost the same task to complete in one of my projects. From experience, I have this small workaround for you to achieve that in not much lines of code.

What I did here:

- Implemented the `box-sizing` hack for all the elements to behave as `border-box` (i.e. include padding),
- Created a `.wrapper` box with an image background. Our content goes in here, with the title with lines on either sides,
- Used CSS pseudo-elements and background gradients to produce the lines on either side of the `.title`,
- Used `table` layout styles to align the lines and the title text in one line, with automatic width adjustment (no matter how long our text is going to be),
- Spaced-up the lines by giving them a width some less than 50%, later pulled them left and right to show up the space
- Added padding to the `.title` to make the lines appear contained, not bleeding out
- Decorated the `.title` a bit to look as close to the image your shared in the question

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #333 url(https://unsplash.it/1200/1000) 0 0 no-repeat / cover;
  padding: 1.5em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
}

.title {
  display: table;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 0 2.5%;
}

.title:before,
.title:after {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  width: 45%;
  display: table-cell;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, currentColor, transparent);
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 1px auto;
}

.title:before {
  right: 2.5%;
}

.title:after {
  left: 2.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">Case Studies</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, consequuntur in, laudantium molestiae dolore voluptate hic blanditiis illo. Reprehenderit fugit assumenda voluptates alias reiciendis eum culpa atque consectetur unde ipsum.</p>
  <p>Quaerat tempore dolores harum quasi aliquam mollitia ipsum officiis. Provident voluptatem, alias atque, pariatur quae placeat ducimus nemo id repudiandae porro natus nobis maxime, impedit ipsum consequatur fugit error molestiae?</p>
  <p>Necessitatibus eligendi, quis, itaque aperiam omnis veritatis quia sequi, ea officiis hic quasi, deserunt blanditiis? Nam eligendi molestias sit cum deleniti. Distinctio id ea blanditiis incidunt, voluptatum, commodi culpa suscipit.</p>
</div>
```

Take a look yourself at the demonstration snippet in the "Full page" view as well.

I hope that answered it well enough. Cheers, happy learning!

Answer (score 0):

```
.section-3-left {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.section-3-left-text {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.section-3-left-text p {
  background: #f3f5f6;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.section-3-left-text:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 8px;
  background-color: #c61000;
  z-index: -1;
}
<div class="section-3-left">

  <div class="section-3-left-text">
    <p>CASE RESULTS</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/ya9rvsbe/

Comment: thanks for your answer but i need the background of the paragraph to be transparent so you can see the image behind it

Comment: i like how you tried to be sneaky and change the background of the paragraph to the same color as the background of the jsfiddle canvas so it appears transparent lol :D

Comment: .section-3-left-text p {
  background: transparent;} set the background as this one

Comment: that does not work, setting to transparent makes the line go through the text still